# Is there a way to print the assert error message inside a except block?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I am practicing with error handling and I have a question. can you make it so the error messages in the assert will be displayed in the except block right now if a error occurs only 'error' is printed and not the actual error message

```
try:
    a = int(input('Please enter the first number it must be >= 200' + '\n' + '(note the sum of both numbers must be <=300)'))
    b= int(input('please your second number it must be <= 50'))
    c = a + b
    assert a >=200 and isinstance(a, int), 'invalid entry for a must be <= 200 and a number'
    assert b<=50 and isinstance(b, int), 'invalid entry for b must be <=50 and a number'
    assert c <= 300, 'The sum of your numbers is >300'
except ValueError
    print('error')
else:
    print('All in range')
```

Comment: The `assert`s in this code never run for non-numeric input. Also, this is not an appropriate use of `assert`. They should not be used to implement program logic. `assert` means "if this is not true, *that proves that there is a bug in the code*".

Answer (score 0):

Add an `except` that catches the `AssertionError` and prints it:

```
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e.args[0] if e.args else "error")
```

Comment: There are so many issues with the original code that trying to answer the question as asked is actively doing a disservice.

Comment: Thank you for that is there any error in my assert statements when I enter say 250 for a it still return all in range rather than an error

Comment: The condition you placed on `a` is that it needs to be *greater* than 200, which 250 is.  Try entering 100.